# deleting some rows from .csv file cause adding NaN columns to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

- python version: 3.7.11
- pandas version: 1.1.3
- IDE: Jupyter Notebook
- Software for opening and resaving the .csv file: Microsoft Excel

I have a .csv file. You can download it from here: https://icedrive.net/0/35CvwH7gqr

In .csv file, I looked for rows that have blank cells and after finding that rows I deleted them. To do this I follow bellow instruction:

- I Opened .csv file with Microsoft Excel.
- I pressed F5, then in the "Reference" field I wrote "A1:E9030", then I clicked on ok.
- I pressed F5 again, then clicked on "Special..." button, select "Blanks", then clicked on ok
- In the "Home" tab from "Cells", I clicked "Delete", then "Delete Sheet Rows"
- saved the file and closed it.

This is the file after deleting some rows: https://icedrive.net/0/cfG1dT6bBr

but when I run bellow code, it seems that extra columns are added after deleting some rows.

```
import pandas as pd

# The file doesn't have any header.
my_file = pd.read_csv(path_to_my_file, header=None)

my_file.head()

print(my_file.shape)
```

The output:
[image]

```
(9024, 244)
```

You can also see the difference by opening the file with notepad:

.csv file before deleting some rows:

[image]

.csv file after deleting some rows:

[image]

before deleting the rows the `my_file.shape` shows me 5 columns but after deleting some rows it shows me 244 for number of columns.

Question:

- How to remove rows in excel or with other ways so I won't end up with this problem?

Note: I can't remove these rows with pandas because pandas automatically doesn't take into account these rows so I should do this manually.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would recommed to load the csv as it is and delete everything you need within jupyter using python

Comment: What program are you running when you delete then resave?

Comment: @JonSG Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the operation you are carrying out in the first part of your question, but I suggest a different solution. Pandas will recognize only `np.nan` objects as null. So, in this case, we could start by loading the .csv file into Pandas first and replace the empty cells with `np.nan` values:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> my_file = pd.read_csv(path_to_my_file, header=None)
>>> my_file = my_file.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Then, we could ask pandas to drop all the rows containing `np.nan`:

```
>>> my_file = my_file.dropna(inplace=True)
```

This should give you the desired output. I think is a good habit to work on data frames from your IDE directly. Hope this helped!